# Why is this ad showing euros?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

The following add is showing the salary range in euros, is this a bug?

Note that I have my location set to the UK and I am in the UK so I would not expect to see this.

Also the location for the job is in France so I don't know if I should be seeing it for that reason as well.

[image: Ad with euro]

Comment: ...because they use Euros in France?

Comment: @jonrsharpe So I don't live in France or use the Euro so to find out my expected salary range I need to go to google or wherever and calculate it myself, a bit backward if you ask me

Comment: They pay the salary in euros, what that converts to in whatever currency you prefer to deal in varies over time and wouldn't be part of the contract.

Comment: @jonrsharpe And I'm sure a decent enough API would keep track of the current rates and when converting to the users preferred currency it will show the updated amount.

Comment: I'm not saying that couldn't be done, but that it shouldn't. The salary is set and offered in Euros, and it would be misleading to show it in a different currency. Putting e.g. *"currently about £Xk"* in *alongside* the actual salary might be OK, but seems of limited value and would likely be more confusing.

Comment: Also, if you are seriously considering a job in another country, sooner rather than later would be a good time to get at least a rough feeling of their currency's value.  The exchange rate tells you what you can buy in your own country with that money, but not necessarily you can buy for it if you actually move there.  The [Big Mac Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Mac_Index) is a good popular illustration.  As of today, a Big Mac will cost you 4.51 in France, but 3.94 in the UK (source: http://www.statista.com/statistics/274326/big-mac-index-global-prices-for-a-big-mac/) ... 5.06 here!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's in Euros because the employer has chosen to list the salary in Euros. Presumably the job pays in Euros. It's located in France, after all.

For context, here is what [the UI for posting a job](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/create) on Stack Overflow looks like. Employers can choose the currency the job's salary is listed in.

[image]

Comment: On what order is the currency listing sorted? (I see (B)ritish Pounds after (E)uros)

Comment: @BhargavRao I haven't checked but I think it's probably alphabetical by [currency code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217). Euros are EUR and pounds are GBP. I don't know why we decided not to support Fiji Dollars (FJD) or Falkland Island Pounds (FKP)!